# How to activate the network in an Android application without leaving the application

Tags: android, networking, geolocation, gps, smartphone

I am developing an application that use the GPS and the geolocalion. So, during the application launch, I have to be sure that the user has activated the network and GPS. If he didn't tested 2 solutions :

- Ask the user to activate them himself (so the application quit, and the user has to reload it)
- Redirect the user in the corresponding view in order to activate them ( via something like "                      android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS " )

The second solution is better to my mind but can be very boring for the user if he has to activate the Network + the GPS + Nework localisation ...

That's why I ask if it is not possible to activate all that automatically if it is not possible ? I think it is possible because it exists widget that let the user activate network, gps etc... but how can we do that in the application ???

thanks for reading ;)

Comment: You should consider using network location (cell tower location); AFAICT, since Android 1.5, GPS can no longer be turned on by applications for privacy reasons.

Comment: Yes I also use cell tower location (but I need to ask the user to activate it, if it is not)

Answer (score 1):

As Lie Rayn says in his comment to your question. You cannot activated GPS directly via code. but I think [this blog post](http://advback.com/android/checking-if-gps-is-enabled-android/) it is what you're looking for.

You can start an activity which then shows the user the "Locations and Security" setting page where GPS can then be activated.

Comment: Ok, that's what I did in the "second solution". I just wanted to be sure that it is not possible to achieve that in an easier manner.
Thank you ;)